# Typescript: Split a big interface

Tags: typescript, interface

I have created an interface for receiving a response from an HTTP request. The response of the service has a lot of elements, so my interface is large.

Interface

```
export interface LargeInterface {
    object_1: string;
    object_2: string;
    object_3: string;
    object_4: string;
    object_5: string;
    object_6: string;
    ...
    object_n: string;
}
```

Call

```
this.http.get<LargeInterface>( this.url, formData );
```

I want to split the interface into parts, but I need that the get method parses it correctly. Which could be a good method?

I tried with inheritance, but I think that it is not a good practice because the relation between the parts of the interface is not based on inheritance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create sub interfaces and combine them to one

```
interface Base_Data {
  object_1: string
}

interface Special_Data {
  object_2: string
}

interface LargeInterface extends Base_Data, Special_Data {
}
```

and use them as intended

```
this.http.get<LargeInterface>( this.url, formData );
```

Comment: I prefer this presentation; is it exactly the same than using '&' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine interfaces with `&`

```
interface I1 {
  object_1: string
}

interface I2 {
  object_2: string
}

type LargeInterface = I1 & I2
```